# Matlab axis spectrum Scaling

Tags: matlab, axes, spectrum

I am doing real time analysis of a signal and I have the Spectrum of it. But I want to change only the Y axis of this spectrum but keep the Spectrum within the Graph. How do I do it? Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to change?  The numeric labels on the `Y` axis? The `Y` axis title? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I want to change the numeric values on the Yaxis.

Comment: To what values? What range?  Your question is very unclear.  Give me a numeric example... from what range to what?

Comment: I have the fft spectrum which shows the magnitude in dBFS(audio signal). When I change my scale to dBV I need the Y axis of the spectrum to change with respect to the dBV values. Since the frequency components remain the same in dBFS or dBV, hence my Xaxis is fine, but I dont know how to change my Y axis values with respect to the dBV scale.

Comment: There is still an insufficient amount of information to help you solve your problem.  If you want to convert between them, you need to know RMS values for your wave form and RMS totally depends on the waveform.  I don't know what structure your waveform takes on so I can't even begin to help you here.  BTW, if you take a look at your [question history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4815247/aditya?tab=questions), almost all of your questions have no answers.  Look at how you're phrasing your questions... they lack a lot of information.  Take that into account the next time you ask a question.

Comment: @Aditya You have three options: 1) Change the variable representing your spectrum before doing the plot. 2) Change the plot values once the plot has been made. 3) Change only the y-axis labels. What do you want exactly? Better give an example with code